# CreateCustomer mutation with customer group magento2

Tags: magento2, graphql, create-account

I am looking for a solution how we can create customer with customer group Id,

In magento frontend we have the customer group drop down.

I am using the createCustomer mutation.

```
mutation {
createCustomer(
input: {
  firstname: "ko2"
  lastname: "89ko2"
  email: "mkji@test2.com"
  is_subscribed: true
  customerGroupId: 1
  }
 ) {
   customer {
    id
    firstname
    lastname
    email
   }
 }
}
```

I am getting below error

> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "Field "customerGroupId" is not defined by type CustomerInput.",

Can anyone help me with this how I can create customer along with the group.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try This Code**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CustomerGraphQl\Model\Resolver\CreateCustomer">
        <plugin name="vendorname_modulename_createcustomerplugin" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\CreateCustomerPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin**

**CreateCustomerPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin;

use Magento\CustomerGraphQl\Model\Resolver\CreateCustomer;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;

class CreateCustomerPlugin
{
    private $storeManager;

    protected $logger;

    private $customerRepository;

    protected $_customerGroupCollection;

    protected $customerFactory;

    public const ATTR_CODE = 'account_status';

    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroupCollection,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->_customerGroupCollection = $customerGroupCollection;
        $this->customerFactory    = $customerFactory;
    }

    public function aroundResolve(
        CreateCustomer $subject,
        $proceed,
        $field,
        $context,
        $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ){
        try{
            $result = $proceed($field, $context, $info, $value, $args);
            $customerEmail = $result['customer']['email'];
            $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
            $customer =  $this->customerFactory->create()->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->loadByEmail($customerEmail);
            $customerId = $customer->getId();
            $groupId = 1;
            if (isset($args['input']['customer_group'])) {
                $customerGroupName = $args['input']['customer_group'];
                $account_status = $args['input']['account_status'];
                $account_status_id = $this->getOptionIdBylabel($customer, self::ATTR_CODE, $account_status);
                $customerGroups = $this->getCustomerGroups();
                $groupInfo = $this->getGroupInfo($customerGroupName, $customerGroups);
                if($groupInfo){
                    $groupId = $groupInfo['value'];
                    if($groupId != 1){
                        $this->updateCustomerGroup($customerId, $groupId, $account_status_id);
                    }else{
                        $this->updateCustomerAccountStatus($customerId, $account_status_id);
                    }
                }
            }
            return $result;
        }catch(LocalizedException $exception){
            $this->logger->error($exception);
        }
    }

    public function getCustomerGroups()
    {
        $customerGroups = $this->_customerGroupCollection->toOptionArray();
        return $customerGroups;
    }

    public function updateCustomerGroup(int $customerId, int $groupId, int $account_status_id): void
    {
        $customer = $this->getCustomerById($customerId);
        if ($customer) {
            try {
                $customer->setGroupId($groupId);
                $customer->setCustomAttribute('account_status', $account_status_id);
                $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
            } catch (LocalizedException $exception) {
                $this->logger->error($exception);
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    public function updateCustomerAccountStatus(int $customerId, int $account_status_id): void
    {
        $customer = $this->getCustomerById($customerId);
        if ($customer) {
            try {
                $customer->setCustomAttribute('account_status', $account_status_id);
                $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
            } catch (LocalizedException $exception) {
                $this->logger->error($exception);
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    private function getCustomerById(int $customerId)
    {
        try {
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
        } catch (LocalizedException $exception) {
            $customer = null;
            $this->logger->error($exception);
        }

        return $customer;
    }

    public function getGroupInfo($customerGroupName, $customerGroups){
        $groupArray = array_search($customerGroupName, array_column($customerGroups, 'label'));
        if($groupArray){
            return $customerGroups[$groupArray];
        }
        return $groupArray;
    }

    public function getOptionIdBylabel($customer, $attribute_code, $account_status){
        try{
            $account_status_attribute = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code);
            if ($account_status_attribute->usesSource()) {
                $account_status_id = $account_status_attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($account_status);
                if(isset($account_status_id) && $account_status_id != ''){
                    return $account_status_id;
                } else {
                    $account_status = 'Activated';
                    $account_status_id = $account_status_attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($account_status);
                    return $account_status_id;
                }
            }
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```